# How do I create a vector which shows the sum of the individual values whenever there are repeated indices?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary ‘d’ which stores a list of indices (d['inds']) and a list of values (d['vals']). For example:
    d['inds'] == [0,   3,   7,   3,   3,   5, 1]
    d['vals'] == [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]
In the above example, the index 3 appears three times. How do I create a vector which shows the sum of the individual values whenever there are repeated indices? In other words, the vector corresponding to this example of d would be:
    # ind:  0    1    2    3*    4    5    6    7
    x == [1.0, 7.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 3.0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dictionary where the keys are the indices and the values are the total sum:

```
d = {
    'inds': [0, 3, 7, 3, 3, 5, 1],
    'vals': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]
}

result = {}
for i, v in zip(d['inds'], d['vals']):
    if i not in result:
        result[i] = 0
    result[i] += v

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{0: 1.0, 1: 7.0, 3: 11.0, 5: 6.0, 7: 3.0}
```

If the list (vector) is mandatory can be done in the following way:

```
result = [0]*(max(d['inds']) + 1)
for i, v in zip(d['inds'], d['vals']):
    result[i] += v

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[1.0, 7.0, 0, 11.0, 0, 6.0, 0, 3.0]
```